# JQueryUI doesn't exist inside ajax.success

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to make JQueryUI make tabs out of some HTML I'm getting back from an ajax request. The function I''m trying to use [ $().tabs() ] isn't defined in the ajax.success function where I need to call it.

Code Below

```
function updateWidgets() {
    for(x = 0; x < model.Widgets.length; x++){
        Widget = model.Widgets[x];
        var context = $(this);
        return $.ajax({
            url: Widget.AjaxUrl,
            success: function (response) {
                $('#' + Widget.StylingID).html(response);
                $('.tabs').tabs();
            }
        })
    }
};
```

HTML

```
<div class="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Server 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Server 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Server 2</a></li>
    </ul>


    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, </p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. </p>
        <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you checked that the page is ready before running the script?  Since it is ajax it could be the markup hasn't rendered by the time the script is running.

Comment: The error it's giving me is that the function is not defined. If I stop at breakpoints before the ajax call it exists. Inside the success it doesn't exist no matter how long I wait.

Comment: *the function is not defined* **Which** function? What's the error exactly?

Comment: $('.tabs').tabs(); the tabs function is a widget of JqueryUI

Comment: Are you sure that it works outside of the ajax?

Comment: Sounds like it may be a case of the function being called before a required  jquery version is loaded.  Make sure you have a script reference to whatever version of jQuery is required for the tabs to work.

Comment: Like I said before it works at the top of the for loop, before the ajax call.

Comment: Error is Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tabs is not a function$.ajax.success @ Dashboard.js:43

Comment: oh, BTW, I set up a deferment function to wait until $().tabs was defined to call this function. It still hit the same error

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript should be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    updateWidgets();
});

function updateWidgets() {
    for(x = 0; x < model.Widgets.length; x++){
        Widget = model.Widgets[x];
        var context = $(this);
        // no need to return as you might not using it as a promise object.
        $.ajax({
            url: Widget.AjaxUrl,
            success: function (response) {
                $('#' + Widget.StylingID).html(response);
                $('.tabs').tabs();
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: The return was a relic of a previous attempt to fix this issue (returning the deferred and tying into the .done event of it) That also didn't work.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for the same, as I am not sure about `model.Widgets` and the response setting to `'#' + Widget.StylingID` this, cannot find this in shared HTML.

Comment: I have no idea how to fake an ajax call in a fiddle.

Comment: model is a JSON object populated by a serialized MVC.NET viewmodel